# $x^n \equiv m \bmod k$ is there a generic formula for int $n$, $m$, $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example $x^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 4$ or $x^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and there are no other solutions for $(2,m,4)$. Edit: I am not about try to solve for $x$, I am looking for the possible $(n, m, k)$ triplets.

Comment: this is known as the discrete log and is hard to calculate

Comment: Formula for what exactly?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling he's asking about solving for $x$, not for $n$.

Comment: No, I am asking for a formula covering n, m and k. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @chx yes, a formula that **gives you x** in terms of $n$, $m$, and $k$.  Is that not what you mean?

Comment: I would describe this problem as that of finding roots to polynomials over $\Bbb Z_k$ (specifically of the form $p(x) = x^n - m$).

Comment: (2,2,4) is not possible for example -- there's no number which gives a remainder of 2 module 4 when squared. I am not after x. I am after only the possible (n, m,k).

Comment: Okay, so you're looking for triplets $(n,m,k)$ *such that* $x^n \equiv m \pmod{k}$ has a solution.  Is that it?

Comment: For $n=2$, this amounts to studying [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).

Comment: Exactly! The existence of a solution is enough.